# CSS Adjusting location of text in HTML lists with List-Style-Image

Tags: html, css, image, list, position

How would I move each of the "Blahs" in the list up a bit so they are more in the middle of each of the list bullets in the picture of my HTML code below.

[image]

The code on its own is simply:

```
<html>
<style>
li
{
margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul style="list-style-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/WvHNgNo.png?2'); margin-top:0px;">
<li>Blah</li>
<li>Blah</li>
<li>Blah</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Also tried changing the padding but that moved both the image and the text, I just want to move the text up.

Comment: Do you have a sample of your html? The solution can vary depending on how you organized your code.

Comment: So, What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style each bullet as a background of the list element with something like `background: url(http://i.imgur.com/WvHNgNo.png?2) no-repeat left 50%;`

In your case is enough style the list item in this way

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/WvHNgNo.png?2) no-repeat left 50%;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 25px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rWXZT/

Answer (score 1):

```
li{
  list-style-type:none;
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/WvHNgNo.png?2) no repeat left 50%;
}
```